# Prevent activating silent mode when screen is locked

Tags: lock-screens, silent-mode

Is there a way to prevent turning the sound (silencing the phone) off from the lock screen? This is a Motorola Droid 4.

I notice I've missed calls and check only to find that the sound has been turned off. I always make sure to turn the screen off thus activating the screen lock when I put the phone in my pocket. However, I see that the touchscreen still allows the speaker to turn off. Is there a way to deactivate this? I tried using the [Droid inPocket](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.addition.inpocket) app and it didn't solve the problem. In fact, I'm not sure what it did do.

Answer (score 0):

- http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-replace-and-customize-android-lock-screen-guide/

[image: from first link]
 - http://www.vikitech.com/6075/best-android-lock-screen-apps

Essentially, if there is not an option in your security settings, you'll need to replace your lock screen.